# Does Python Polars have a function similar to Pandas with read_fwf ( for reading fixed-width formatted files)

Tags: python-polars

Does Python Polars have a function similar to Pandas read_fwf ( for reading fixed-width formatted files)? Need to read txt files with fixed width data of the type below, and then apply a schema with columns based on positions in the file.

*Sample Data:*
A1G01409xxx xxxx                                                           T  30499759910.001099101000199105100105430021  47.570952   -53.32332502xxxxxx                   WW19921220190000010AAA11
A31124xxxxxx No.  1, Subd. U                                              SNO21499649910.001099101000199105100107410182  47.166651   -52.88563505MOBILE                        WW19921220190000011NNN51
A3B01339Division No.  1, Subd. G                                              SNO35799759910.001003701000299105100105000122  47.945009   -53.06603613                          WW19921220190000011NNN51
A3P01379                                                                 T  35799759910.001099101000101364100105250252  47.678897   -53.25694413RIVERHEAD                 WW19921220190000011NNN52

*Illustrative schema:*
schema_dict = {
"Postal_codeOM": (1, 6),
"FSA": (7, 3),
# ... and so on for other columns ...
}

Comment: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/8312

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@jqurious is right here there are some solutions but not directly a function `read_fwf` inside polars.

You can generate a list of polars expressions with a for loop inside with_columns and make your own purpose `read_fwf`.

See here for the first time it appears on GitHub issues:

https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/3151#issuecomment-1397354684

quoting @ghuls example (`str.strip()` becomes `str.strip_chars()`):

a sample fwf file:

```bash
$ cat fwf_test.txt
NAME                STATE     TELEPHONE  
John Smith          WA        418-Y11-4111
Mary Hartford       CA        319-Z19-4341
Evan Nolan          IL        219-532-c301
```

you have column names, column widths and calculate "slice tuples" for substring full string column.

```py
df = pl.read_csv(
    "fwf_test.txt",
    has_header=False,
    skip_rows=1,
    new_columns=["full_str"]
)

column_names = [ "NAME", "STATE", "TELEPHONE" ]
widths = [20, 10, 12]


# Calculate slice values from widths.
slice_tuples = []
offset = 0

for i in widths:
    slice_tuples.append((offset, i))
    offset += i

df.with_columns(
    [
       pl.col("full_str").str.slice(slice_tuple[0], slice_tuple[1]).str.strip_chars().alias(col)
       for slice_tuple, col in zip(slice_tuples, column_names)
    ]
).drop("full_str")
```

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌───────────────┬───────┬──────────────┐
│ NAME          ┆ STATE ┆ TELEPHONE    │
│ ---           ┆ ---   ┆ ---          │
│ str           ┆ str   ┆ str          │
╞═══════════════╪═══════╪══════════════╡
│ John Smith    ┆ WA    ┆ 418-Y11-4111 │
│ Mary Hartford ┆ CA    ┆ 319-Z19-4341 │
│ Evan Nolan    ┆ IL    ┆ 219-532-c301 │
└───────────────┴───────┴──────────────┘
```

Then you can read see @jqurious link which is much complete with types casting, but iteration over zip(slice tuples, names, ...) remains the same logic.

It's faster than many `read_fwf` implementations without polars.

Comment: Amazing and huge thanks for your help! I was trying to handle four big text files (280MB each) with Dask on my i7 with 32GB RAM, but it kept crashing. After using your Polars code with some modifications, it worked super fast and finished everything in just 2.9 seconds! I am adding the modified script as the an answer.

Comment: You're welcome. I've just pass the message.  By the way it's quite funny, Medium daily digest informs me this morning about your post! https://medium.com/@arkimetrix.analytics/part-7-python-polars-working-with-fixed-width-files-edge-case-9a7b1e710b98

Answer (score 1):

Adapted from Guillaume's solution above, code to read multiple files. Also, defined 'column_names' as a list of strings to label each column clearly, and 'cols' as a list of tuples to specify the start and end positions of each column in a fixed-width format. Encountered an issue where characters like "," were disrupting the schema detection. To resolve this, added a Parameter with a character not present in the file (using separator="|").

```py
import polars as pl
import time
import glob


folder_path = "/path/*.txt"
all_data = []  # List to hold all the data frames

for file_path in glob.glob(folder_path):
    try:
        # Read the entire file as a single column DataFrame
        df = pl.read_csv(
            file_path,
            has_header=False,
            skip_rows=0,
            separator="|",  # required only if the txt file contains "," and assumes no "|"
            new_columns=["full_str"],
            encoding="ISO-8859-1",  # Adjust encoding as necessary
        )

        # Append the cleaned DataFrame to the list
        all_data.append(df)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing {file_path}: {e}")

# Combine all DataFrames into one
# Combined_df contains all the data from the txt files as one column
combined_df = pl.concat(all_data)

# Define cols widths (start,end)
cols = [(0, 6), (6, 9), ...]

# Define col names
column_names = ["Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3", ...]


# Define a function to extract substrings based on the start and end positions
def extract_substrings(df, cols, column_names):
    expressions = []
    for (start, end), name in zip(cols, column_names):
        # Adjust for zero-based indexing and slice the string
        expression = pl.col("full_str").str.slice(start, end - start).alias(name)
        expressions.append(expression)
    return df.select(expressions)


# Apply the function to get a DataFrame with the defined columns
df = extract_substrings(combined_df, cols, column_names)

# Save the resulting DataFrame
df.write_parquet("path/dataframe.parquet")
```