# Reading a fixed width file with Rust

Tags: parsing, rust, fixed-width, rust-polars

I am trying to read a fixed width file with `Rust`, with the goal to load the data into a `Polars` dataframe, however, I can't parse the file correctly.
I am trying to use the `fixed_width` crate as `polars` lacks the utility to parse such files.
Unfortunately, the `fixed_width` documentation does not have any example where a file is read, all the examples read data from a string...

Here is my failed attempt (the commented code works as it is a copy-paste from the docs) and obviously, the file contains same data as the string:

```
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};
use fixed_width::{FixedWidth, FieldSet, Reader};


fn main() {
    let r_file = "path/to/file.r01";
    // let data = String::from("R   5001.00   1001.00                          513777.5 2093285.7   0.0\nR   5001.00   1002.00                          513786.6 2093281.6   0.0\nR   5001.00   1003.00                          513795.7 2093277.4   0.0\nR   5001.00   1004.00                          513708.8 2093273.3   0.0\n");

    #[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
    struct SpsRecord {
        pub line: f32,
        pub point: f32,
        pub easting: f32,
        pub northing: f32
    }

    impl FixedWidth for SpsRecord {
        fn fields() -> FieldSet {
            FieldSet::Seq(vec![
                FieldSet::new_field(1..11).name("line"),
                FieldSet::new_field(11..21).name("point"),
                FieldSet::new_field(46..55).name("easting"),
                FieldSet::new_field(55..65).name("northing")
            ])
        }
    }

    impl SpsRecord {
        fn from_file(path: &str) -> Result<Vec<Self>, fixed_width::Error> {
            let mut reader = Reader::from_file(path)?;
            let records: Result<Vec<Self>, fixed_width::Error> = reader
                .byte_reader()
                .filter_map(Result::ok)
                .map(|bytes| fixed_width::from_bytes(&bytes))
                .collect();
            match records {
                Ok(records) => Ok(records),
                Err(err) => Err(fixed_width::Error::from(err))
            }
        }

        // fn from_string(data: &str) -> Result<Vec<Self>, fixed_width::Error> {
        //     let mut reader = Reader::from_string(data).width(72);
        //     let records: Result<Vec<Self>, fixed_width::Error> = reader
        //         .byte_reader()
        //         .filter_map(Result::ok)
        //         .map(|bytes| fixed_width::from_bytes(&bytes))
        //         .collect();
        //     match records {
        //         Ok(records) => Ok(records),
        //         Err(err) => Err(fixed_width::Error::from(err))
        //     }
        // }
    }

    println!("Reading {}...", r_file);
    match SpsRecord::from_file(r_file) {
        Ok(records) => {
            for record in records {
                println!("{:?}", record);
            }
        }
        Err(err) => {
            eprintln!("{:#?}", err);
        }
    }

    // println!("Reading\n{}...", data);
    // match SpsRecord::from_string(&data) {
    //     Ok(records) => {
    //         for record in records {
    //             println!("{:?}", record);
    //         }
    //     }
    //     Err(err) => {
    //         eprintln!("{:#?}", err);
    //     }
    // } 
}
```

The code runs, prints the "Reading..." line and does absolutely nothing, so I don't know where to look.

Comment: Note that your code does nothing if it was able to read the file, but there were no `records` found. Try adding a `println` inside the `Ok(records)` branch, before the `for record in records` loop.

Comment: @Jmb I just tried that and it does print, so it seems the `println!("{:?}", record);` line is not working out as expected, but I have no idea what exactly is going on as it is working fine in the commented code (the string version)

Comment: In the string version, you call `.width (72)`. Why don't you call it in the file version?

Comment: @Jmb I tried but the method isn't available on the `Reader` created with `from_file`, it turns out you have to `unwrap` it first, that's why I didn't do it in the first place. That and the fact that I assumed a file reader would likely return entire lines, having to give it explicitely the length of the lines felt counter intuitive to me.

Comment: You don't need to `unwrap`, but you need to call `.width` _after_ the `?` as in `Reader::from_file(path)?.width (72)`

Comment: A string reader could return entire lines just as well as a file reader, but the `fixed_width` doesn't assume anything about the input: it could just as well be binary data without any separation between records.

Comment: Also note that by default `fixed_width` doesn't handle line breaks specially: it just assumes that they are part of the current record. If you want to split on line breaks, you need to call the [`linebreak`](https://docs.rs/fixed_width/0.5.1/fixed_width/struct.Reader.html#method.linebreak) method first.

Comment: @Jmb yes, I finally got it to work, actually, there are some examples using `from_file` in the test section of the github repo... well hidden, but worth having a look at! That's where I saw the `unwrap` being used before calling `width`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation directly with rust-polars inspired by the [python one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77742011/10527496).

The idea is to read the file as one column and split it with polars slice expressions.

As an example here two types are generated: integer and character but it's possible to extend the ugly if/else, would be better to use a match to infer polars types from short types (c : char, i : int, d : date).

temp_file_fwf.txt

```
000000001Strawberryfieldsforever
000000002Strawberryfieldsforever
000000003Strawberryfieldsforever
000000004Strawberryfieldsforever
000000005Strawberryfieldsforever
000000006Strawberryfieldsforever
```

```rust
pub fn main() {
    use polars::prelude::*;

    // Specify columns positions and lengths, names and types of columns to parse
    let column_names:   Vec<&str> = vec!["col_1", "col_2", "col_3", "col_4"];
    let column_starts:  Vec<i64>  = vec![0, 9, 19, 25];
    let column_lengths: Vec<i64>  = vec![9, 10, 6, 40];
    let column_types:   Vec<&str> = vec!["i", "c", "c", "c"];
    
    // initialize a vector to "list" polars expressions, on per column
    let mut _vec_expr:Vec<Expr> = vec![];

   let mut _i = 0;


    while _i < column_names.len() {
                // character first
            if column_types[_i] == "c" {
                // if character then slice 
                _vec_expr.append(&mut 
                vec![col("l").str()
                .slice(column_starts[_i], Some(column_lengths[_i].try_into().unwrap()))
                .alias(column_names[_i])]);
            } // if integers then slice and cast to integer (i32 here) 
            else if ["i"].contains(&column_types[_i]){
                // integer next
                _vec_expr.append(&mut 
                vec![col("l").str()
                .slice(column_starts[_i], Some(column_lengths[_i].try_into().unwrap()))
                .cast(DataType::Int32)
                .alias(column_names[_i])]);
        }
        _i +=1;
    }

    println!("{:?}", _vec_expr);

    let path = "temp_file_fwf.txt";
    // Read with csv reader lazily (if you have comma in the file, change the delimiter)
    let data_ = LazyCsvReader::new(path)
    // read just one column named "l" for line
    .with_schema(Some(Arc::new(Schema::from_iter(vec![Field::new("l", DataType::Utf8)]).into())))
    .has_header(false)
    // test 100 first lines
    .with_n_rows(Some(100))
    .finish()
    .unwrap();

    // append the polars lazyframe with the expressions generated above
    let data_ = data_
            .with_columns(
            _vec_expr
            );

    // collect
    println!("{:?}", data_.collect());
    
}
```

```
[col("l").str.slice().cast(Int32).alias("col_1"), col("l").str.slice().alias("col_2"), col("l").str.slice().alias("col_3"), col("l").str.slice().alias("col_4")]
Ok(shape: (6, 5)
┌──────────────────────────────────┬───────┬────────────┬────────┬─────────┐
│ l                                ┆ col_1 ┆ col_2      ┆ col_3  ┆ col_4   │
│ ---                              ┆ ---   ┆ ---        ┆ ---    ┆ ---     │
│ str                              ┆ i32   ┆ str        ┆ str    ┆ str     │
╞══════════════════════════════════╪═══════╪════════════╪════════╪═════════╡
│ 000000001Strawberryfieldsforever ┆ 1     ┆ Strawberry ┆ fields ┆ forever │
│ 000000002Strawberryfieldsforever ┆ 2     ┆ Strawberry ┆ fields ┆ forever │
│ 000000003Strawberryfieldsforever ┆ 3     ┆ Strawberry ┆ fields ┆ forever │
│ 000000004Strawberryfieldsforever ┆ 4     ┆ Strawberry ┆ fields ┆ forever │
│ 000000005Strawberryfieldsforever ┆ 5     ┆ Strawberry ┆ fields ┆ forever │
│ 000000006Strawberryfieldsforever ┆ 6     ┆ Strawberry ┆ fields ┆ forever │
└──────────────────────────────────┴───────┴────────────┴────────┴─────────┘)
```

Duplicated on the github polars repo: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/13632